# Data Binding - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I want to bind TextBox's Text property to FolderBrowser's SelectedPath property. But it's not working, I don't know why. Please help me out why it's not working?

Comment: It will b e difficult to help if you don't show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data binding makes very little sense here.  Just make your code look like this:

```
  if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    // User picked a path and didn't cancel the dialog...
    textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
  }
```

Comment: yes sure but I want to know why it doesn't work with data binding?

Comment: I don't know, you haven't said squat about how you tried to bind it.